# How to get the JSON Object name if it contains hyphen or dash (-) like this "nearby-cities" using Volley Library in android studio?

Tags: json, android-studio, android-volley

```
JSONArray nearbyCities = products.getJSONArray("nearby-cities");
JSONObject nearbyCititesObj = content.getJSONObject("nearby-cities.json");
```

The Object to retrieve is properties->products->nearby-cities->contents->nearby-cities.json

Here the problem to retrieve is `nearby-cities` and `nearby-cities.json` object and array respectively.

> below is the link for the json file
>   https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nc73408691.geojson

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Could you please post your complete code

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen will not make any difference. Your error is probably somewhere else

```
response.getJSONObject("properties").getJSONObject("products").getJSONArray("nearby-cities").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("contents").getJSONObject("nearby-cities.json").toString();
```

This line gives the expected output